# Replicate MATLAB's `conv2()` in Frequency Domain

Tags: image-processing, matlab, fourier-transform, convolution, software-implementation

When `conv2d` is on `same` mode, the image needs no padding, because the result is the same size as the image.

When `conv2d` is on `full` mode, the result is `(image_width + kernel_width -1) * (image_height + kernel_height -1)`.

Then how do I pad the image?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253984/linear-convolution-of-two-images-in-matlab-using-fft2

Comment: @ZRHan Very helpful! Thank you so much! Should I delete my question because of duplication?

Comment: I think closing it is OK.

Comment: @MageFront, I wrote a full answer. Don't delete. Please mark my answer.

Comment: Related https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56407.

Comment: Related https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70908.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a MATLAB function which is basically `conv2()` applied in Frequency Domain:

```
function [ mO ] = ImageConvFrequencyDomain( mI, mH, convShape )
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% [ mO ] = ImageConvFrequencyDomain( mI, mH, convShape )
% Applies Image Convolution in the Frequency Domain.
% Input:
%   - mI                -   Input Image.
%                           Structure: Matrix.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double' (Single Channel).
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
%   - mH                -   Filtering Kernel.
%                           Structure: Matrix.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
%   - convShape         -   Convolution Shape.
%                           Sets the convolution shape.
%                           Structure: Scalar.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: {1, 2, 3}.
% Output:
%   - mI                -   Output Image.
%                           Structure: Matrix (Single Channel).
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
% References:
%   1.  MATLAB's 'conv2()' - https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html.
% Remarks:
%   1.  A
% TODO:
%   1.  
%   Release Notes:
%   -   1.0.000     29/04/2021  Royi Avital     RoyiAvital@yahoo.com
%       *   First release version.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

CONV_SHAPE_FULL     = 1;
CONV_SHAPE_SAME     = 2;
CONV_SHAPE_VALID    = 3;

numRows     = size(mI, 1);
numCols     = size(mI, 2);

numRowsKernel = size(mH, 1);
numColsKernel = size(mH, 2);

switch(convShape)
    case(CONV_SHAPE_FULL)
        numRowsFft  = numRows + numRowsKernel - 1;
        numColsFft  = numCols + numColsKernel - 1;
        firstRowIdx = 1;
        firstColIdx = 1;
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
    case(CONV_SHAPE_SAME)
        numRowsFft  = numRows + numRowsKernel;
        numColsFft  = numCols + numColsKernel;
        firstRowIdx = ceil((numRowsKernel + 1) / 2);
        firstColIdx = ceil((numColsKernel + 1) / 2);
        lastRowIdx  = firstRowIdx + numRows - 1;
        lastColdIdx = firstColIdx + numCols - 1;
    case(CONV_SHAPE_VALID)
        numRowsFft = numRows;
        numColsFft = numCols;
        firstRowIdx = numRowsKernel;
        firstColIdx = numColsKernel;
        % The Kernel when transformed is shifted (Namely its (0, 0) is top
        % left not middle).
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
end

mO = ifft2(fft2(mI, numRowsFft, numColsFft) .* fft2(mH, numRowsFft, numColsFft), 'symmetric');
mO = mO(firstRowIdx:lastRowIdx, firstColIdx:lastColdIdx);


end
```

It is fully compatible and validated.
The full code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q74803 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q74803` folder).

Comment: I don't get how you're matching `conv2`  without centering `mH`, does MATLAB do something different with `fft2` or `ifft2`?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Nevermind, you compensate by changing unpad indices. Looks good.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, If I got you write, then indeed, the `fftshift()` you use in your methods is not needed. For performance it is better not to use it. Just need to understand the axis system of the transformation.

Comment: If `mH` isn't reused and we're not aiming for circular convolution, yes. But it's more confusing to debug and doesn't enjoy offset-invariance in strided context. I'm so used to it that I forgot this alt case, I should mention it in my answer.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, Even for circular convolution there is not need to center it. On the contrary.

Comment: Output at index `i` won't correspond to the filter centered at index `i`. I don't think that's ever desired if we want input and output axes aligned?

Comment: We like it, but for the analysis, not for the computation. Once you verify the implementation it is a black box.

Comment: You said no need for circular, meaning no padding. The axes get only more messed up with higher dimensions. If you're doing circular template matching, or anything that wants index 5 to be 2 centimeters for both input and output, the output is wrong without `ifftshift2`, and not even contiguous.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, Not sure what you're talking about. Circular convolution is by definition the multiplication in frequency. I have never had the issues you're talking about.

Comment: If $h$ is a bird and $x$ is unit impulse, both visually centered as in virtually any application with input images, then the bird will have legs for ears at output. The four quadrants are shifted in nonsensical manner. If $x$ is another bird and you want to find its location (obviously in original coordinate space), you will fail without `ifftshift`.

Comment: Put such a question and we'll see :-).

Comment: Considering your self-admitted unfamiliarity, you should be the one to open it. I have also already shown it [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/85962/50076).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, I am not unfamiliar, I think you're wrong. If you have doubts, you can ask. If not, it is OK on my side. I don't need any shift in my matched filter algorithms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145416/discussion-between-overlordgolddragon-and-royi).