# Using FFT, iFFT separate instead of FFT2, iFFT2 for a convolution? is it possible?

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution, ifft

I'm testing implementing a convolution by using an FFT way. Reference Link: [Replicate MATLAB's `conv2()` in Frequency Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74803/replicate-matlabs-conv2-in-frequency-domain)

as you see, he uses fft2 & ifft2 and it works perfectly. But I want to use traditional FFT & IFFT for each col, row

My forward direction is ok. However, the inverse direction has problems that make my result go wrong. Can anyone know where I am doing something wrong?
I put my re-write code here:

```
   function [ mO_1 ] = conv2_rewrite( mI, mH, convShape )
% CONV_SHAPE_FULL     = 1;
% CONV_SHAPE_SAME     = 2;
% CONV_SHAPE_VALID    = 3;

numRows     = size(mI, 1);
numCols     = size(mI, 2);

numRowsKernel = size(mH, 1);
numColsKernel = size(mH, 2);

switch(convShape)
    case('full')
        numRowsFft  = numRows + numRowsKernel - 1;
        numColsFft  = numCols + numColsKernel - 1;
        firstRowIdx = 1;
        firstColIdx = 1;
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
    case('same')
        numRowsFft  = numRows + numRowsKernel;
        numColsFft  = numCols + numColsKernel;
        firstRowIdx = ceil((numRowsKernel + 1) / 2);
        firstColIdx = ceil((numColsKernel + 1) / 2);
        lastRowIdx  = firstRowIdx + numRows - 1;
        lastColdIdx = firstColIdx + numCols - 1;
    case('valid')
        numRowsFft = numRows;
        numColsFft = numCols;
        firstRowIdx = numRowsKernel;
        firstColIdx = numColsKernel;
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
end
fftsizeRow = 2^(nextpow2(numRowsFft));
fftsizeCol = 2^(nextpow2(numColsFft));
% test fft separable instead fft2
fft_data = fft(mI,fftsizeRow,1);
fft_data1 = fft(fft_data,fftsizeCol,2);

fft_kernel = fft(mH,fftsizeRow,1);
fft_kernel1 = fft(fft_kernel,fftsizeCol,2);
% test ifft separable instead ifft2
% mO_fft2 = ifft2(fft2(mI, fftsizeRow, fftsizeCol) .* fft2(mH, fftsizeRow, fftsizeCol), 'symmetric');
% mO = ifft2(fft_data1 .* fft_kernel1, 'symmetric');
mO = ifft(fft_data1 .* fft_kernel1,fftsizeRow,1, 'symmetric');
mO = ifft(mO, fftsizeCol, 2, 'symmetric');
mO_1 = mO(firstRowIdx:lastRowIdx, firstColIdx:lastColdIdx);
% mO_1_fft2 = mO_fft2(firstRowIdx:lastRowIdx, firstColIdx:lastColdIdx);
end
```

Thanks!

Update figure (the data and output look like):
input -> noiseLevel = conv2(input, kernel) -> input/noise + threshold
[image]

[image]

It's hard to analyze why I'm wrong on some frames. Of course, there are many other factors in the processing but when I use fft2, and ifft2 there are no errors. I don't know what happens in this frame:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to DSP.SE. Can you please elaborate what do you mean when you say that "it goes wrong"? Do you have minimal example that you can add?

Comment: Please show your expected output and actual output, so we have some idea of what your (perceived?) problem is. Your code looks OK at first glance.

Comment: Sorry!! I can't share the data. But I can say my data is a radar signal, not an image, but I can treat them like an image. I use a convolution way to filter out the background noise. However, when I use my way, background noise is still there.